# Trouble loading in mixed data from txt file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, matrix, load, data-files

I'm trying to load in data from a text file. The first two rows are headers, following the headers the first two columns are date and time. The rest of the columns are floats.

data should have 11 columns, however, `whos` returns that size is only 1x3

Data txt file:
[image: DATA TABLE]

```
fid = fopen('allunderway.txt', 'rt');
data = textscan(fid, '%{M/dd/yyyy}D %{HH:mm:ss}D %4.2f %2.4f %2.5f %2.4f %2.4f %2.2f %4.2f %3.1f %1.4f', 'HeaderLines', 2, 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);
whos data
date = data{1};
time = data{2};
wnd_td = data{10};
wnd_ts = data{11};
```

Comment: Did you try the `read_table` function instead? Otherwise, could you provide your data file in txt in order to give a try?

Comment: I tried `readtable` and got `Warning: Unable to determine the format of the DATETIME data. ......
Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid
MATLAB identifiers. `

Comment: I tried adding in %D ... `T = readtable('allunderway.txt', '%{M/dd/yyyy}D %{HH:mm:ss}D %4.2f %2.4f %2.5f %2.4f %2.4f %2.2f %4.2f %3.1f %1.4f', 'HeaderLines', 2);` but an error for `readtable` that says wrong number of arguements

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a delimiter instead, seems like this is a tab separated file.
you might have to try both 'rt' and 'r' in the fopen command.
As for the textscan part try adding this

```
'Delimiter','\t','EmptyValue',NaN
```

It adds tabs as a delimiter and replaces empty values with NaN. 
or uses spaces as delimiters and set it so that it doesn't matter if there's 1 or multiple spaces

```
'Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1
```

Or use 'Whitespace' as the delimiter (uses both tabs and spaces).

Comment: @Rose if this helps you, please upvote it. If it solves your problem, please accept it. If you're having trouble and need help, please respond and ask.